# How to use std::string to store bytes (unsigned chars) in a right way?

Tags: c++, lz77

I'm coding LZ77 compression algorithm, and I have trouble storing unsigned chars in a string. To compress any file, I use its binary representation and then read it as `chars` (because 1 char is equal to 1 byte, afaik) to a `std::string`. Everything works perfectly fine with `chars`. But after some time googling I learned that `char` is not always 1 byte, so I decided to swap it for `unsigned char`. And here things start to get tricky:

- When compressing plain .txt, everything works as expected, I get equal files before and after decompression (I assume it should, because we basically work with text before and after byte conversion)
- However, when trying to compress .bmp, decompressed file loses 3 bytes compared to input file (I lose these 3 bytes when trying to save unsigned chars to a std::string)

> So, my question is – is there a way to properly save unsigned chars to
>   a string?

I tried to use `typedef basic_string<unsigned char> ustring` and swap all related functions for their basic alternatives to use with `unsigned char`, but I still lose 3 bytes.

> **UPDATE:** I found out that 3 bytes (symbols) are lost not because of
>   std::string, but because of `std::istream_iterator` (that I use instead
>   of `std::istreambuf_iterator`) to create string of unsigned chars
>   (because `std::istreambuf_iterator`'s argument is char, not unsigned
>   char)

So, are there any solutions to this particular problem?

Example:

```
std::vector<char> tempbuf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {}); // reads 112782 symbols

std::vector<char> tempbuf(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), {}); // reads 112779 symbols
```

Sample code:

```
void LZ77::readFileUnpacked(std::string& path)

{


std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (file.is_open())
{
    // Works just fine with char, but loses 3 bytes with unsigned
    std::string tempstring = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});
    file.close();
}
else
    throw std::ios_base::failure("Failed to open the file");
}
```

Comment: When is a `char` not 1 byte?

Comment: Why not std::vector?

Comment: @Eljay
I read that on some platforms char can not be equal to 1 byte (because apparently Standard doesn't define its exact size). Anyway, what are your thoughts on storing byte data using regular char in general? Is it optimal enough?

Comment: @IgorR.
It's the worst case scenario, because it will require to rewrite most of algorithm's logic

Comment: I'd use `std::vector<std::byte>` to store the byte data.  If you want to avoid rewriting that much code, then `std::basic_string<std::byte>` (may have to provide your own traits, too).

Comment: It's not just storing – I need to compress this data, and `std::byte` doesn't provide enough interface (also I read that `std::byte` is `unsigned char` in disguise)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is std::vector<uint8_t>. I'm uncertain support of uint8_t is guaranteed by the standard, but if it is, it will have exactly 8 bits.

Comment: You don't want to use `std::string` - in many places it is assumed that strings are null-terminated and this isn't what you want. Use `std::vector`. There is no need to worry over `char` being not 8 bits. Such systems are rare and most surely something else is not going to work on it besides your small archive code.

Comment: @ALX23z slim chances unsigned char would be different from uint8_t, but as a matter of software engineering its better to explicitly state to the compiler what one is trying to achieve, so on the rare occasion one would get a clear compilation error, rather than unclear run time error.

Comment: `std::vector<std::byte>>` . Done. Discussion over.

Comment: @asymmetriq "*I read that on some platforms char can not be equal to 1 byte (because apparently Standard doesn't define its exact size)*" - the standard does explicitly say that `char` is one byte in size (that `sizeof(char)` always returns 1). What it does not say is how large a byte is. And yes, there are platforms (albeit rare nowadays) where a byte is not 8 bits in size. See `CHAR_BIT` for the actual size on a given platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` in all of its forms (and `std::byte`, which is isomorphic with `unsigned char`) is always the smallest possible type that a system supports. The C++ standard defines that `sizeof(char)` and its variations shall always be exactly 1.

"One" what? That's implementation-defined. But every type in the system will be some multiple of `sizeof(char)` in size.

So you shouldn't be too concerned over systems where `char` is not one byte. If you're working under a system where `CHAR_BITS` isn't 8, then that system can't handle 8-bit bytes directly at all. So `unsigned char` won't be any different/better for this purpose.

---

As to the particulars of your problem, `istream_iterator` is fundamentally different from `istreambuf_iterator` iterator. The purpose of the latter is to allow iterator access to the actual stream as a sequence of values. The purpose of `istream_iterator<T>` is to allow access to a stream as if by performing a repeated sequence of `operator >>` calls with a `T` value.

So if you're doing `istream_iterator<char>`, then you're saying that you want to read the stream as if you did `stream >> some_char;` variable for each iterator access. That isn't actually isomorphic with accessing the stream's characters directly. Specifically, [FormattedInputFunctions like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) `operator>>` can do things like skip whitespace, depending on how you set up your stream.

Comment: To clarify a bit...

Section 4.4 of C++17 (IIRC this is new to this standard) says "The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (5.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation defined."

So I take it that, starting with C++17, CHAR_BITS must be at least 8.

Comment: @UriRaz, CHAR_BITS must be at least 8 since C90.

Comment: @UriRaz -- `CHAR_BITS` has always had to be at least 8 (look up its definition in the library portion of the C standard). But it can (and sometimes is) more than 8. On some (ancient) systems the smallest addressable unit of storage was 9 bits wide (so `CHAR_BIT` would be 9), and integers were 36 bits. On some modern systems (specifically, DSPs) the smallest addressable unit of storage is 32 bits wide, so `CHAR_BIT` is 32.

Answer (score 1):

`istream_iterator` is reading using `operator>>` which usually skip white spaces as part of its function.  If you want to disable that behavior, you'll have to do

```
#include <ios>

file >> std::noskipws;
```